Gradient and Zero norm
Suppose that $f:\mathbb{R}^n\to\mathbb{R}$ is a continuously differentiable function. Under which condition the following set is finite
$$X=\left\{x\in\mathbb{R}^n:\begin{array}{ll}
\text{if}~\|x\|_0<s \Rightarrow \nabla f\left(x\right)=0.&\\
\text{if}~\|x\|_0=s \Rightarrow\left[\nabla f\left(x\right)\right]_i=0, \quad \forall i:x_i\neq 0.\end{array}
 \right\},$$
where  $\|x\|_0 := \#\{i : x_i \neq 0\}.$

Not sure why you would delete your original question, including my example of a continuously differentiable function for which there are no such conditions, only to ask the exact same question again.

For example, a strictly convex function works here. Do you have any other weaker conditions?
@HenrikAlsingFriberg
